# How add a metadata for this old token?

Tags: solana-cli, token, metadata

I've tried everything but I can't update the metadata of this token of mine

what could be the problem?
https://solscan.io/token/9bnKvEK2ymzbrtKGeCSbDtn7Dr1afCQoTTH1y4fL5seK

Comment: what should I do If i have the mint authority.

Answer (score 3):

To add metadata to a token mint, you must sign with the token's mint authority.  Unfortunately, this mint has no mint authority:

```
$ spl-token display 9bnKvEK2ymzbrtKGeCSbDtn7Dr1afCQoTTH1y4fL5seK

SPL Token Mint
  Address: 9bnKvEK2ymzbrtKGeCSbDtn7Dr1afCQoTTH1y4fL5seK
  Program: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
  Supply: 18000000000000000000
  Decimals: 9
  Mint authority: (not set)
  Freeze authority: (not set)
```

Unless you've already added token metadata previously, in which case you can use the configured metadata update authority.

Comment: earlier i created token using solana-tokens repost for this i cant create metadata in metaplex how can i fix this?

Comment: If you don't have existing metadata for this token, it's impossible to create the metadata without the mint authority signature for this token. This is one of the unfortunate weaknesses in the design for the program